# C++ syntax error in constructor - arugment is reference to object from another class

Tags: c++, object, constructor, reference

i want to access methods and fields from class Product in class Menu.
So i write the following code:

*Menu.h*

```
#include "Product.h"
class Menu{
public:
  Menu(Product& prod);
  Menu();
private:
  Product product;}
```

*Menu.cpp*

```
 #include "Menu.h"
 Menu::Menu(Product& prod) { this->product = prod; }
 Menu::Menu() {}
```

*Product.h*

```
 #include "Menu.h"
 Class Product{
 public:
    Product():
}
```

and i get the following error in Menu constructor:
syntax error: identifier  'Product'.

i changed Menu constructor to:

```
Menu(const Product& prod)
```

but it didn't work too.

Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Currently it's unclear what is declared in `Product.h` (if class `Product` is even declared there).

Comment: Product is an empty class with no field and no methods with defualt constructor but i added it.

Comment: Put the semicolon after the class definition like that: `class Menu {...};`

Comment: @qblacksheep Your `Product` class wouldn't compile due to this line: `Product():`. As I mentioned - provide [mcve]. In addition, why does `Product.h` need to include `Menu.h`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cleaning up your code from the errors, it looks like this and compiles like a charm:

**Menu.h**

```
#include "Product.h"

class Menu {
public:
    Menu(Product& prod);
    Menu();
private:
    Product product;
};
```

**Menu.cpp**

```
#include "Menu.h"

Menu::Menu(Product& prod)
{
    product = prod;
}

Menu::Menu()
{

}
```

**Product.h**

```
class Product {
public:
    Product()
    {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

remove #include "Menu.h" from Product.h

and yes, please provide a full example.

Comment: If there are header guards, surely that doesnt make a difference.

Comment: @SamerTufail Did you see any header guards in the example shown?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius usually they are auto generated and when posting examples, usually they are not added. Point being I would wait for [mcve]

Comment: @SamerTufail No, header guards won't help circular dependency.

Comment: @songyuanyao They do otherwise the guards are pointless https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard and ofcourse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127171/how-are-circular-includes-resolved

Comment: @SamerTufail Auto generated, by what? If they are auto generated by your tool of choice, it doesn't mean that they are, by whatever OP is using.

Comment: @SamerTufail you are mistaken. Include guards protect against multiple inclusion, not against circular dependencies. There is no way to resolve curcular dependencies mechanically.

Comment: @n.m. agreed, this is a case of multiple inclusion camaflouged under the term 'circular dependency' - the orginal solution above need not be if guards are used or #pragma once. Circular dependency between classes and multiple inclusion of the same header file are seperate issues.