# invalid use of incomplete type error in pimpl idiom

Tags: c++, design-patterns, pimpl-idiom

**foo.h**

```
#include"fooImpl.h"

    class foo
    { 
        private:
            class fooImpl; 
            std::unique_ptr <fooImpl> foo_imple;
        public:
            void bar();  
    };
```

**fooImpl.h**

```
#include "foo.h"

    class foo::fooImpl 
    {
        public: 
            void api();  
    };
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo::bar()
{
    foo_imple->api();
}
```

**fooImpl.cpp**

```
#include"foo.h"
#include"fooImpl.h"

void foo::fooImpl::api()       
{   
    cout << "bar"; 
}
```

**Getting the following error:**

> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class foo::fooImpl'
>     foo_imple->bar();
>
> note: forward declaration of 'class foo::fooImpl'
>      class fooImpl;

Not able to find out whats wrong with this pimpl implementation. Error looks like due to some declaration missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are circular #includes resolved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127171/how-are-circular-includes-resolved)

Answer (score 4):

This is more typical:

**foo.h**

```
class foo
{ 
    private:
        class fooImpl;
        std::unique_ptr <fooImpl> foo_imple;

    public:
        void bar();
        // Non-inline destructor so we don't need a definition for fooImpl
        ~foo();
};
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

class foo::fooImpl
{
    public:
        void api()
        {
            cout << "bar";
        }
};

void foo::bar()
{
    foo_imple->api();
}

foo::~foo() = default;
```

Notice that now you don't need to expose anything about the `fooImpl` to users of `foo` - the class is completely hidden. You also avoid having additional header and cpp files if `fooImpl` is only used in your `foo.cpp` source file, otherwise you could put it and its method definitions inline in a `fooImpl.h` that only needs to be included in `foo.cpp`.

Comment: Better: `foo::~foo() = default;` (in the same location, not inside the class)  But yes, controlling the destructor definition is very necessary as noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8595471/103167

Comment: @ChrisHunt In my case, I must move the impl to a separate file. This is because of ownership/modularity constraints of the project.

Answer (score 3):

In order to call `foo_imple->bar();` class declaration from `fooImpl.h` should be available. While for `foo` class declaration there is no need to include `fooImpl.h`

Comment: So, what edits are you suggesting? Adding fooImpl.h to foo.cpp and removal of #include"fooImpl.h" from foo.h?

Comment: @ShibirBasak Exactly.

Comment: Worked! Thanks.

Comment: This fix *doesn't* work if `fooImpl` has any non-trivial destructor.  See @ChrisHunt's answer and also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8595471/103167 for the fix.

Comment: Getting this, when using assert in api() --> /usr/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:74:22: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'foo::fooImpl'
  static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
                      ^

Comment: @ShibirBasak I don't see any `assert` in `api()`, so I guess you are asking about some code that not present in the question, right? Putting assert in the `api()` as it written here should not cause any problems because class `fooImpl` is complete at that point.

Comment: @BenVoigt This fix *does* work regardless of whether `fooImpl` has trivial or non-trivial destructor since this class will be complete in both translation units mentioned in the question. The link you posted is indeed helpful, however even with an explicit destructor of `foo` the includes should be rearranged as written in my answer.

Comment: @VTT. Even without any assert. This code gives error :  Complete error log here: ...... c++/6.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of 'void std::default_delete<_Tp>::operator()(_Tp*) const [with _Tp = foo::fooImpl]': ... required from 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = foo::fooImpl; _Dp = std::default_delete<foo::fooImpl>]' ... error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'foo::fooImpl' static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,

Comment: @ShibirBasak Are you sure that error comes from `fooImpl.cpp` and not from other translation unit? Note that without explicit destructor for `foo` class `fooImpl` definition must be available in every translation unit that uses `foo`.

Comment: @VTT An object of foo was created by another translation unit. I added inline constructor and destructor in foo.hpp. This error was resolved when I moved them to foo.cpp. Thanks to Modern Effective C++ by Scott Meyers : Item 22: When using the Pimpl Idiom, define special member functions in the implementation file.